# Select2 adds extra span on back button with Laravel & PJAX

Tags: jquery-select2, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1, pjax, jquery-select2-4

I'm using PJAX with Laravel.

My pages have multiple select2 inputs. When pressed back button *of the browser*, the page gets extra `<span>` added beneath the original input. This span seems to be a replica of select2's `select2-container`. However, the select input (html tag) itself is not being replicated and works fine with select2 initialized on it properly.

If repeated multiple times (go to one page, press back, repeat) each cycle adds one new `<span>` input. The navigation seems to be working fine otherwise.

Any help would be helpful. Thanks.